# Where should I stash meta information for an html element?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I don't know if this question is titled appropriately.

I have a sidebar populated with clickable divs that represent objects in a database. When the user clicks one of these divs, I would like to fetch more detailed information via ajax and display the received information in a main content area.

Each sidebar div needs to have an associated `id` with it that I can pass to the server with my javascript.

I am wondering where I should put this id on the page?

Is there a best practices way of doing this?

Comment: Consider using `<a href="...">` for the clickable elements and check in your server-side script if the request is an AJAX request (via the X-Requested-With header) and either send whatever you need in your script or a whole page if it wasn't an AJAX request. This allows search engines to properly index the loaded data and users without JavaScript will be able to use your site, too.

Comment: I think this makes the most sense, because I want search engines to index this content. But how do I make it so that the link doesn't get followed when javascript is running, but does get followed otherwise? use onclick and return false?

Comment: [`e.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the event handler function with `e` being the function's first argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would store the data in [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

jQuery has a method [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to easily retrieve / store data.

For loading partial views from the server I would recommend [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: That looks beautiful Jakub, would love to hear explanation for the downvote on this one.

Comment: Data-attributes are perfect for this. +1

Comment: Downvotes may have been from the fact that the OP didn't mention jQuery, but this answer goes into using jQuery to fetch date from `data-` attributes.  With or without jQuery, `data-` is still the best way to store custom attributes on tags, as they are HTML5 compatible.

Comment: Question is tagged with `jquery` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing it is to have the clickable regions in the form anchor links to go to url that fetches the data in json format.

Something like this:

```
<a href="/getdata?id=1234" class="data_expand"  rel="nofollow">Expand</a>
```

And then:

```
$(function(){

    $(".sidebar a.data_expand").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

       $.get($(this).attr("href")).then(function(data){
           //Handle data here
       });
    });

});
```

Comment: Do search engines like it better this way? or indifferent?

Comment: See my edit for nofollow rel tag. This will make sure that search engines will ignore it.